# How to add column in customer group table using script?

Tags: magento-1, customer-group

We need to add 3 more column in the customer group table.

How to add it using script?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$installer = $this; 
$installer->startSetup();   

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('customer_group'), 'my_custom_field1', 'varchar(100)');
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('customer_group'), 'my_custom_field2', 'varchar(100)');

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Need to: 1st => With **Decimal with price formate**, 2nd => with **Int**

Comment: "varchar(100)" replace to "DECIMAL(12,4)" and try

Comment: What about For **Int** ?

Comment: "varchar(100)" replace to "INT(11)" and try